# Maximum Entropy Markov Model for Named Entity Recognition in Java

Tags: java, nlp

I have a parsing problem that would be solved really well by a MEMM.  But I have spent far to much time trying to find a good implementation of the algorithm (ideally in java).  Has anyone done this before?  Alternatively I could implement it myself if some-one has some readable documentation.

Thanks!

(I have already tried Mallet and the trainer in the jar was unimplemented)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Stanford NLP Group's [***CMMClassifier***](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/ner/CMMClassifier.html), found in [**Stanford CoreNLP suite of NLP tools**](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)?

I'm afraid I cannot speak to the quality of the underlying [***MEMM***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum-entropy_Markov_model) implementation, but it is in Java, and I've used several other parts of Stanford NLP with relative success.

I find that sometimes the drawback of CoreNLP is its extensive object model and the very many dependencies that most modules have.  When one wishes to focus on a single tool/class the distraction and learning curve associated with these dependencies can be annoying.  On the other hand, this object model effectively corresponds to actual lower and mid-level processes which are common to many NLP tasks and hence can be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

What is your reason for thinking MEMMs are particularly good for your problem? Usually it is very hard to find theoretical justifications why something would work better than something else and the question is resolved empirically.

If you have Mallet already, try using the Conditional Random Field implementation. Recent research, starting with Lafferty, McCallum and Pereira's `Conditional Random Fields: Probabilistic Models for Segmenting and Labeling Sequence Data` shows that CRF is often superior to MEMM for sequence tagging.

Comment: +1 --- CRFs are the de facto standard for probabilistic sequence labelling. You'd need a very good reason not to use them.